# Would you participate in a chat event? What topics for that event would be appealing to you?

Tags: discussion, chat

After [discussing the idea of a chat event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/conversation/chat-event-possibilities)...with some of the active users of Seasoned Advice's chat room, I propose that we try it out this week or next week.

Firstly, this is an opportunity for anyone who is opposed to the idea on principle to speak up before I start scheduling things.

Secondly, I'd like to hear any ideas that users have for a chat event topic. Even if you haven't participated much or at all in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/16/the-frying-pan), your ideas are more than welcome. The goal is to have a fun discussion about an interesting cooking-related topic, generate interest in the chatroom for users who didn't know it existed / never participated before, and to generally get to know each other a little better.

One chat topic per answer please, so votes can be used to express favor or disapproval of individual topics. (If you hate the idea of chat events in general, you can downvote the question.)

Answer (score 2):

### International Holiday Foods

Pick your favorite holiday, and tell us what you like to cook during that time. This would be a great way to learn about regional food traditions, personal family traditions, or fun and unusual holiday foods. Photos and recipes welcome.

This coincides with Thanksgiving (US) and entering the Christmas season, but discussion of any holidays are welcome. Doesn't have to be holidays that are close to now in the calendar. :)

Comment: This event took place on November 22, 2011. The transcript can be found in the conversations tab of the room info: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/16/the-frying-pan?tab=conversations

Answer (score 0):

### Holiday Cookie Exchange

During the International Holiday Foods chat, much of the conversation focused on Christmas. Since this is a widespread holiday that for many people centers around food, and it's coming up soon, maybe we could have a series of chat events to discuss different aspects of a culinary Christmas. We spent a bit of time talking about cookies and other baked goods, which led me to the idea for this chat.

Participants can come prepared with a description of their favorite holiday cookie, its origins/personal traditions, and maybe even a recipe or photos to share. If we do it in the next couple of weeks, it will hopefully inspire people to make and share some new treats this Christmas. And the transcript will be a delicious little repository of cookie ideas.